# Rearranging and Matching Array Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to simplify an array with Javascript

```
[{
{name: orange,
quanity: 1},
{name: apple,
quanity: 3}
}]
```

I want

```
[{
orange:1,
apple: 3
}]
```

I have tried

```
const keys = flat.map(item => {
            item.name = item.quanity
        })
```

But I get

```
[ undefined, undefined ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want an array of 1 element instead of an object. also your input doesn't look valid . maybe `Object.fromEntries(arr.map(e => [e.name,e.quanity]))`

Comment: I am trying to simplify larger sets of data to create charts using D3

Comment: Your example object is syntactically invalid.  You have something of the form `[{ {}, {} }]`  Perhaps the outer `{ }`'s are a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the key-value pairs you want in the final object from the `map` callback, then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create the combined object.

```js
let arr=[{name:"orange",quanity:1},{name:"apple",quanity:3}];
let res = [Object.fromEntries(arr.map(o => [o.name, o.quanity]))];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note : Input given in the question is not valid JavaScript syntax**

The input given in the question is an array of objects, where each object represents a fruit and its corresponding quantity. To transform this input into the desired output, you can use the following code:

```
const arr = [
  { name: "orange", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "apple", quantity: 3 }
];

const ans = {};
arr.forEach(({ name, quantity }) => {
  ans[name] = quantity;
});
```

This code initializes an empty object ans and then iterates over each object in the input array using the forEach method. For each object, it extracts the name and quantity properties and adds them to the ans object as a key-value pair.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, using `.reduce()`:

```js
let original = [
  {
    name: 'orange',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    quantity: 3
  }
];

let res = original.reduce((a,{name, quantity})=>(a[name]=quantity,a),{});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but slightly different solution, compared to the one from Unmigitiated. Both are nice and short.

```js
let original = [
  {
    name: 'orange',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    quantity: 3
  }
];

let simpler = original
  .map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.quantity }))
  .reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), {});

console.log(simpler);
```

Comment: but this has a different format?

Comment: In which way? You mean that I corrected the spelling of quantity?

Comment: nope i meant instead of a single object with multiple props. this still creates multiple objects with single prop

Comment: oh you're quite correct... will edit...

Comment: but then no array should be necessary? maybe that was a mistake in the question?

Comment: @ThomasFrank LOL, thanks I have corretced this :)

Comment: I edited my solution - still quite short, but not as short as Unmitigated. :) 
All good. Whoever edited my answer so it works 'run code snippet' - thanks I'll remember to use those for these kind of questions from now on.

Comment: why map and then reduce? just reduce

Comment: You are right - that would be one possibility (there's another answer here that does that already. :) Actually I missunderstood the question initially since it was published with an array around the singular object and created multiple objects and then just threw in a reducer quickly to fix it... So not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Your input data structure is not valid. You need to remove the extra curly braces, and quote the string values (and maybe spell "quantity" correctly). So you're left with:

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'orange', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'apple', quantity: 3 }
];
```

There are a few ways to get the output you want but maybe the easiest is to use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration##for...of_statement) loop to iterate over the array. You can then use the `name` and `quantity` values to populate the property keys/values of an output object. If you want that object to be the only element in an array you can wrap the object later.

Note: since we don't know if the object names are unique I've added an additional object to the data so you can see how the addition works in this example.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'orange', quantity: 1},
  { name: 'apple', quantity: 3},
  { name: 'orange', quantity: 32 }
];

// Empty object
const out = {};

// Iterate over the array.
for (const obj of arr) {

  // Destructure the name/quantity propertied
  // from each object
  const { name, quantity } = obj;

  // If the key identified by the name doesn't
  // exist on the output object create it and
  // set it to zero. This means that it doesn't matter
  // if there is more than one object with the same name.
  // If there are post-first object this line of
  // code will be ignored.
  out[name] ??= 0;

  // Update the property value with the
  // quantity value.
  out[name] += quantity;
}

// Wrap the object in an array
// should you need to
console.log([out]);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)